# I cannot right click on the desktop

Tags: 12.04, compiz

It was activating a few options of compiz config, but when it activates the option "wallpaper", to be able to have different images in every office. first I unite awhile the screen, which is normal, that in order that it works this option it is necessary to deactivate a thing in ubuntu tweak or in gnome tweak tool, after deactivating it works perfectly. But later I realized that when I right click on the desktop nothing happens. I found that for arregrarlo `gconf-publisher` had to open, go to apps > nautilus > preferences, and to activate show "desktop", but me this option does not appear, only it goes out saying:

```
desktop fond, navigation_window_saved_geometry, 
navigation_window_saved_maximized
start_with_sidebar.
```

Comment: Did you try alt+right click?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Or else, you can also use Ubuntu Tweak 0.7.1to do the same. Simply download and install it by running these one by one from a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then start Ubuntu tweak, go to Tweaks menu, select Desktop Icons, and change Show Desktop Icons to On. Basically it does the same thing as what

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

does, but Ubuntu Tweak can also come in handy if you need some system-tweaking quickly, without using complicated codes.

Thanks.

Comment: For mate in 14.04 it is `gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons true`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```