# Icons have disappeared from desktop, and right-click fails

Tags: gnome-classic

I can't right click anything and there aren't the usual icons on my desktop. 
I'm using Gnome classic.  I think there was a gnome setting that turns off or back on.

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I cannot right click on the desktop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140944/i-cannot-right-click-on-the-desktop)

Comment: Duplicate of [How to configure GNOME 3 to show icons on desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/43246).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by the OP:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```