# Wallpaper is not changing and right click does not work on desktop in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, desktop-environments, desktop-background

Sorry if this question is already answered, but I have already searched and could not find a solution to my problem.

Recently I installed `gnome-shell` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` to try gnome. I then removed it using

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop.
```

From that moment I couldn't change my desktop wallpaper. Also, when I right click on my desktop it doesn't work.

I read in some links to check if xfdesktop is running...
In my ubuntu, that process is not running.
When I run xfdesktop from terminal, it gives me the following error:

```
SESSION_MANAGER environment variable is not defined. Failed to connect to session manager.
```

I don't know if it has any relation to my problem.

Another thing I observed is that gnome-system-monitor and gnome-session are still running on my ubuntu... why are they running if I want Unity only?

Is there any way to reset my ubuntu to as it was initially. But I have also installed some useful applications and packages in this, can I keep them even after resetting?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of or at least very similar to [287571](http://askubuntu.com/questions/287571/desktop-shows-a-white-or-black-background-instead-of-wallpapers)
Gnome-shell disables Nautilus handling the desktop and so on Unity no wallpaper and no destop-icons are available anymore.

Comment: Thank you @Christian, this started changing the wallpaper. But Still right click and super key is not working when I am at Desktop.

Comment: Is Gnome-Tweak-Tool still installed? There is an option to let Nautilus handle the desktop. This must be set.
According to the second answer to the mentioned question, this can also be done with "ubuntu-tweak-tool" which I do not know.

Comment: I think this might help you:
 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/140944/i-cannot-right-click-on-the-desktop/141086#141086

Comment: The gnome tweak tool did it for me, the option was already set, I just toggled it and it started working again. I not have backgrounds and can right click

Answer (score 85):

I had the exact same problem. 
Tried everything in the book! 
This is what worked for me. 
 Hope your problem is solved soon.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

Comment: Worked !! But what was the reason? I didn't get it.

Comment: @Karan: I agree--what's the rationale here?

Comment: This solution gave me back my changing wallpapers, but didn't allow me to click. This fixed the clicking problem for anyone that needs it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/142247/why-doesnt-right-click-work-on-my-desktop

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04.2. It's bizarre how something basic like this could be broken out of the box...

Comment: also worked!  I had variety installed, and it wasn't working.  I am very curious how this isn't a default setting.  Still no context menu on a right click, but I never really used it anyway.

Comment: Worked nicely for me as well!  I suspect this might have happened when I used the gnome-tweak tool to disable desktop icons.

Anyone else who had this issue disable desktop icons via command line?

Answer (score 10):

After installing or removing of `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` a bug of Desktop not responding to clicks/icons can occur, You may reactivate:

Active Desktop Background:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
```

Active Desktop Icons:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `gnome-tweak-tool`.
Click the Desktop button (left side)
Set:

```
Mode = Scaled
Background Location = ...image path
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too after I installed Gnome-Shell. Uninstalling it and rebooting restored the desktop clickability and brought back the desktop icons too.