# How do I remove all traces that Ubuntu Tweak was ever there? - revised

Tags: 14.04, unity, lock-screen, ubuntu-tweak

I have an image hovering in my lock-screen that I can't remove. I think I put it there with Ubuntu-tweak but I have already uninstalled it.

Any ideas on how to remove it?

I really hope this is the only issue it left me with but only time will tell.

**edit - more details**

[lock-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie52q.jpg)

I think i might have replaced the "Ubuntu 14.04" logo with Darth lighting a smoke.

A - Reinstalled and set to default, and then uninstalled it again

- The first part is solved but now it seems like I can't make any changes in my standard appearance settings.

So the new question is how to remove all traces of Ubuntu Tweak?

Comment: install tweak again and change the lock screen

Comment: @Mohammedaadhil That worked but I still can't make any changes to my appearance in the standard settings. New question... How do I remove all traces that Ubuntu Tweak was ever there?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (Ctl + Alt+T) and type `sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-tweak` and confirm. This will remove all ubuntu tweak pakages you can also run `sudo apt-get autoremove` after this to remove all resources for the application.

Comment: It might have worked but I still don't have the ability to set my wallpaper to anything

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the tweak tools using APT per the post by DnrDevil.  I believe what you are dealing with is a bug in 14.04.  Are you running Gnome?  If so try this command and you should be able to set the wallpaper through the gnome GUI.

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true`

Also if you are missing desktop icons on top of this run this one:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`

Source: [Wallpaper is not changing and right click does not work on desktop in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527366/wallpaper-is-not-changing-and-right-click-does-not-work-on-desktop-in-ubuntu-14)