# What is desktop environment?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

I am new to Ubuntu. What is desktop environments, and how do I install them?
I tried to install Gnome using Terminal but I couldn't.

Comment: What steps have you taken and what were the actual results?

Comment: @StephenM.Webb http://askubuntu.com/questions/450294/how-to-switch-from-unity-to-gnome.     I tried this. But the look was as unity with no launcher bar and the task bar bottom

Comment: That is a different question then "What is desktop environments"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A desktop Environment is, put very simply, a window manager (graphical interface) + other utilities on top of the operating system.

If you want to install gnome:

Log out of your current session then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

If you get any errors after installing, try

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

If you don't, then

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

Then you can click the little icon next to your log in name and should be good to go

Comment: If you install or remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop and a problem of Desktop not responding for clicks and not show icons you can try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527366/wallpaper-is-not-changing-and-right-click-does-not-work-on-desktop-in-ubuntu-14/836300#836300

Comment: That is not really correct. A window manager is a basic graphical environment and a Desktop environment is a window manager + additional user services such as search functions and other utilities.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-desktop-environment-and-a-window-manager and https://www.maketecheasier.com/difference-between-windows-managers-desktop-environments/ and  similar

Comment: @bodhi.zazen so you're saying a DE is not a graphical interface on top of an OS? I respectfully disagree with you but thank you for your input

Comment: I think you are unclear on the difference between a window manager and a desktop environment. Although it may seem a minor difference to you, the question is "What is desktop environment" and simply stating it is a graphical interface is imprecise as linux is made of components. Technically the graphical interface is X (or mir or wayland ...).

Comment: Ok now I understand the point you are trying to make. I agree with you there. Based on the question and OP stating "new user", I didn't think a "technical" answer was appropriate.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer based on your comments. thank you